# Starting audio streaming from a BLE event when in the background

Tags: ios, avfoundation, core-bluetooth

I have an app which uses the `bluetooth-central` `UIBackgroundModes` key to enable it to process incoming BLE peripheral characteristic value changes whilst the app is backgrounded.

I have a specific characteristic value change which is intended to start an audio streaming activity. This behaviour functions as expected whilst the app is in the foreground, but when backgrounded I see the log messages implying the task is started - but I never hear audio.

I presume when in the BLE background mode, it is not possible to start either the network session to receive audio data, or the audio session itself to begin playback. I cannot, however, find a specific reference to this in the Apple Developer documentation.

Does anyone know if it is possible to achieve the desired behaviour?

Comment: Have you specified the audio background mode key?  Do you already have your audio session established before you move to the background?

Comment: Yes I have an audio background key. No I don't enable the audio session if, at the point I background, I'm not playing audio. Is it "allowable" to enable it beforehand?

Comment: I can't talk to allowable, I suspect not, but only Apple can say. I can see, however, how they wouldn't want an app in the background to suddenly start playing audio. It could be a poor user experience